# when i type the edit text every letter immediately added to the text view in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I have characters typed in a text box appear in a separate text view as soon as they're typed?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add  [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to `EditText` to update `TextView` when any word typed by user

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int end) {

  yourtextview.append(s.toString());

}
```

Comment: NOTE :- you will need to manage if typed char's removed by user

Comment: @yogi : most welcome friend :)

Comment: :can you please do one favour

Comment: @yogi : now where you are facing issue?

Comment: when i type the letter in edit text this letter will repeated again and again(i.e) for example: i want to type prosper when i type p till add to text view but next i type r the the text view having value ppr..like this added then my final out put is pproprosprospprospeprospere....but i actually need prosper only...please help me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22075/discussion-between--k-and-yogi)

Comment: If u see the message please come to chat... i need a help

Comment: @yogi :http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22075/discussion-between--k-and-yogi

Comment: prosper sorry here network problem thats why late....if u free mean come to chat

Answer (score 1):

You need a `TextWatcher`

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```